# Java how to pass a BiFunction as a parameter

Tags: java, lambda

I need help figuring out how to pass this BiFunction

```
BiFunction<Integer, List<Integer>, Integer> func = (a, b) -> {
        int result = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        for(Integer ele : b) {
            temp = b.get(ele);
            result += temp;
        }
        return a + result;
    };
```

I am using this junit test

```
void testFoldLeft() {
        LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) l.addFirst(i+1);
        Integer u = fp.foldLeft(0, l, func(0,l));
    }
```

I am attempting to pass the BiFunction func through foldLeft, which looks like this

```
static <U,V> V foldLeft(V e, Iterable<U>l, BiFunction<V,U,V> f){
    return null;
}
```

What func is supposed to do is to take a list, in this case b, sum up all the elements in b then add that number to a and return the result. However, Eclipse gives me an error stating that func is undefined. I'm new to BiFunctions so I'm kind of stuck here. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hey! Could you post the whole test class?

Answer (score 0):

I think the mismatch is caused by an incorrect declaration of the second parameter of `foldLeft`. If, in your example, `Integer` is the `Iterable`'s argument, then your method should be declared like this:

```
static <U, V> V foldLeft(V e, Iterable<V> l, BiFunction<V, U, V> f) {
    return null;
}
```

`V` is the element type of the iterable, not `U` (which, in this case, would be equivalent to `Iterable<V>`).

Further, your invocation should look like this:

```
Integer u = foldLeft(0, l, func);
```

You can't invoke an expression in Java. Unless `func` is declared as a method in visible scope, `func()` will always be invalid.

---

Note that you can simplify your generics by getting rid of `U` (I don't see a specific need for the type variable for the list type here, but I may be missing some use cases):

```
static <V> V foldLeft(V e, Iterable<V> l, BiFunction<V, Iterable<V>, V> f) {
    return null;
}
```

You do not show your implementation of `foldLeft`, but I'm sure it's going to need to iterate over the list, or at least pass it to `f.apply`. So I suppose you can make the function take a `List<V>`:

```
static <V> V foldLeft(V e, List<V> l, BiFunction<V, List<V>, V> f) {
    return f.apply(e, l);
}
```

Otherwise, calling `f.apply(e, l)` would fail as `Function<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>, Integer>` and `Function<Integer, Iterable<Integer>, Integer>` are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. `func(0,l)` is a syntax error, just pass `func` variable as the `BiFunction`. No need for providing arguments:

   ```
   Integer u = foldLeft(0, l, func);
   ```
2. The generics signature of `foldLeft` does not match the `BiFunction`. Given the current way it is written, `Iterable<U> l` makes the compiler infer `U` as `Integer`, hence the compiler expects the third argument to be a `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>` instead of `BiFunction<Integer, List<Integer>, Integer>`. To make `U` match the `LinkedList<Integer>`, declare it as follows:

   ```
   static <U extends Iterable<V>, V> V foldLeft(V e, U l, BiFunction<V, U, V> f){
       return null;
   }
   ```

Side note: I wonder what the function code is doing:

```
for(Integer ele : b) {
    temp = b.get(ele);
    result += temp;
}
```

This is looping over elements of `b` and treating them as indices. I doubt this is what you want.